# sails lift error in sail.js application in command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sails.js

I try to run the sail application but I got an error  when using sails lift.I followed the procedure to install the sail.js. I created one notepad file I uses the command node C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js lift and save as sails.bat file and put into C:\Windows\System32.but still I got an error can anyone solve this error? Thanks in advance....

```html
I followed the procedure:


C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi>cd AppData

C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData>cd Roaming

C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming>cd npm

C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm>sails new xyz
=====================================================
You seem to be using NPM >= v3.0.0, which no longer
supports symbolic links in the `node_modules/` folder.
As of Feb. 2016, the Sails team is still working on a
speedier solution to optimize `sails new` that will
be released as a 0.12.x patch. But in the mean time,
your new Sails app's dependencies must be set up
using `npm install`.
Because of this, creating your new Sails app will
take longer than you might be used to. Please bear
with us; or if you have a need for speed, downgrade
to NPM < v3.0.0 in the mean time.  Thanks!
=====================================================
Installing dependencies... (this could take a little while)
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN prefer global coffee-script@1.10.0 should be installed with -g
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
added 261 packages in 22.306s
info: Created a new Sails app `xyz`!

C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm>cd xyz

C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\xyz>npm install
up to date in 3.282s

C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\xyz>sails lift

C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\xyz>node C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js lift
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Vignesh'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$ sails new sdc
$ cd sdc
$ npm install
$ sails lift
```

What you are missing?

- You are running `sails lift` in a wrong directory

Comment: C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tgxapp>node C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js lift
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Vignesh'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3

Comment: Just do `npm install sails -g` instead of `C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js`

Comment: whatever I gave in sails.bat file?It is right or wrong?

Comment: Seems like the issue is with the space in folder name.
try this,
`node "C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\xyz\app.js"`

Comment: C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\xyz>cd app.js
The directory name is invalid.

Comment: app.js is a file and not a directory